# Do variables defined in index.js transfer over to other scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, require, module.exports

I have index.js running the following code:

```js
var ClassData=require("./server/classdata.js");
var data=require("./server/data.js");
```

The classdata.js file contains multiple classes, and I was wondering if there is any way to get that into data.js. As of now, the following code is:

```js
var data={};

console.log("hello1"); //this gets logged
module.export=data;
console.log("hello2"); //this gets logged

console.log(ClassData); //"ClassData is not defined"
```

The data object gets exported when the last line is not there, otherwise with it there it says that ClassData is not defined.
I know I can probably define it using the same way I did in index.js, using `require();`, but I would think that makes it run the whole script again. Is there a way to just get it straight from data.js such that it is defined? Would I need to put it in the data.require part? I don't care if I can't change ClassData.

Answer (score 0):

> The classdata.js file contains multiple classes, and I was wondering if there is any way to get that into data.js

You can use `require('./classdata.js')` inside of data.js, that is what `require` is for, reusing a module inside another.

> I know I can probably define it using the same way I did in index.js, using require();, but I would think that makes it run the whole script again.

Modules imported with `require` are [cached after their first](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) use so the script will not run again.